# FOR loop in hexa in batch file

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, hex

I have a batch script with this line inside.

(hex.exe is just giving me hex value of the file between the 2 flags)

```
hex.exe -b -s 0x40E -e 0x40F "%%f"
```

And I want it to be in a loop, in order to execute this line for 0x40E, 0x48E, 0x50E, 0x58E...
But I can't find a way to make it work.

Hope that makes sense!

The complete batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set /a count = 0
for /r %%f in (*.stl) do (
    echo %%f
    FOR /f "tokens=1 delims= " %%a in ('c:\hex.exe -b -s 0x48E -e 0x48F "%%f"') do (
    if %%a==00 (
        echo %%f >> list.txt
        set /a count += 1
        xcopy /Y %%f f:\Subs\fail\         
        )
    )
)
echo !count! >> list.txt
endlocal
```

EDIT
So I'll explain more what I'm trying to do. I want to sort my subs files according to a test of some bits in this file. The list in output is the list of failed files, and these files are also pasted in another directory. My only problem is to completely make the test. Right now it works only on the 0x48E bit, but I want to test it for other bits, so I want to change -e and -s. The range is the 40 first iterations, but I don't know how to make for loop with that kind of step in hex.

Comment: Please clarify a bit what range you want? you're giving some examples but not complete.

Comment: I suppose you would want something like `for %%i in (0x40E 0x48E 0x50E 0x48E) do ..` but if you have huge ranges, that will take a while and would easier to do a `for /L` loop with some sequences.

Comment: No, it doesn't make sense, you need to explain whether you are wanting to change `-s` or `-e` in each case. I would also expect to see the actual and expected output of `list.txt` and the respective changes to `f:\Subs\fail` too. You need to understand that the majority of potential helpers here, have no knowledge of your third party executable, and are not sat in front of your PC. You would get a far greater chance of a solution, if you provide sufficient information for us to replicate your environment and actual issue. My understanding is that you have not attempted the task yourself.

Comment: [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60261409/edit), to include all the information required for us to assist you with your task. Potential helpers cannot be expected to scroll through the comments, in order to piece together what they need to help you. The more difficult you make it, the less chance you have of receiving the assistance you require. _Then delete the comment above, which will no longer be required once you've fulfilled that action_.